# Emacs orgmode agenda: bashscript automatically export year to ical

Tags: bash, emacs, export, org-mode, icalendar

I manually export my agenda year-view periodically to ics and upload it to my site, where it is subscribed by google calendar. It works; but it takes enough time to draw a year view and export it to ics, I'd like to do this automatically via a bash script. How can I do this? Right now I do it manually in emacs as follows:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> agenda

<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>

<kbd>C-w</kbd>cal.ics

and then run my upload script.

Comment: Instead of writing a bash script you might want to consider automating the task *in Emacs*. You have two options for that: 1. Record a [keyboard macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html) and bind it to a key. (After all, "Emacs" stands for "Editing macros".) 2. Define a custom command (i.e., an [interactive function](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Commands.html)) and bind that to a key. // This reduces the overall workflow to 1. Press key binding for macro/command in Emacs. 2. Run upload script.

Comment: Good suggestion; thanks. But there are two reasons I don't take that route: first, the agenda commands are process-consuming and I would like to run them in a separate emacs instance (which would add one more step to a manual solution); and I would like to have them run perhaps via Cron during pre-set idle times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you trying to create an icalendar file, or just write your year agenda out? To write icalendar file out for the year:

```
emacs --batch --user $USER --eval "(progn (org-agenda-list nil nil 'year) (org-icalendar-combine-agenda-files))"
```

will put it in ~/org.ics
If you just want to capture the year agenda as text, what junaleon writes does it.

Comment: Nice catch; I hadn't noticed the format of the output with JuanLeon's answer. This does it.

Answer (score 3):

This shell command will  generate the ICal file for a year based on your agenda data:

```
emacs --batch --user $USER --eval "(progn (org-agenda-list nil nil 'year) (write-file \"cal.ics\"))"
```